# cannot find -lpq after upgrading PostgreSQL 8 to 9 on CentOS 5

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, centos

I'm trying to upgrade a (proprietary, closed-source, legacy) database-driven application from using PostgreSQL 8.1 to PostgreSQL 9.4. I have it installed on a virtual machine running CentOS 5.9. Here's a rough summary of what I've done so far:

1. Downloaded and installed the PostgreSQL 9.4 RPM package from [yum.postgresql.org](http://yum.postgresql.org):

   ```
   $ wget http://yum.postgresql.org/9.4/redhat/rhel-5-x86_64/pgdg-centos94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm
   $ yum install pgdg-redhat94-9.4-1.noarch.rpm
   ```
2. Installed all the postgresql94 packages:

   ```
   $ sudo yum install postgresql94*
   ```
3. Dumped my current database to a file:

   ```
   $ sudo su postgres
   $ pg_dumpall > dump.sql
   ```
4. Uninstalled the the old postgresql packages:

   ```
   $ sudo yum remove postgresql postgresql-*
   ```
5. Sym-linked the new postgres94 bin directory to the location of the old postgres bin directory:

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/ /usr/bin/pgsql
   ```
6. Initialized a postgres94 database and loaded the dump file:

   ```
   $ /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.4 initdb
   $ /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.4 start
   $ /usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/psql < dump.sql
   ```

Then I tried to run the application. For the most part it seemed to work, but it had a few quirks. After a brief attempt at debugging I realized that the application was also using the PostgreSQL C API. So I tried to re-compile the program:

7. Reconfigure:

   ```
   $ ./configure
   ```
8. Check that the include directories and the library directories are configured correctly:

   ```
   $ cat Makefile | grep -P '\-I|\-L'

   PG_CFLAGS = -I/usr/pgsql-9.4/include
   PG_CFLAGS_SERVER = -I/usr/pgsql-9.4/include/server
   PG_CXXFLAGS = -I/usr/pgsql-9.4/include
   PG_CXXFLAGS_SERVER = -I/usr/pgsql-9.4/include/server
   PG_LDFLAGS = -L/usr/pgsql-9.4/lib
   ```
9. Double-check the postgres include and library directories:

   ```
   $ pg_config --includedir

   /usr/pgsql-9.4/include

   $ pg_config --libdir

   /usr/pgsql-9.4/lib
   ```
10. Recompile:

    ```
    $ make clean
    $ make > make.out 2> make.err
    ```
11. Check error output:

    ```
    $ cat make.err
    /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    [...]
    make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
    ```

So it looks like the linker can't find the libpq library, but I'm not sure why. Help?

Comment: Are you sure the app's `configure` actually respects `pg_config`? check `config.log` to see what libdir it's finding, which pg_config it used, etc. Also consider removing configure's cache and doing a make clena.

Comment: I'm looking through config.log, but I don't see any other -I or -L directives. I also don't see any evidence of /usr/lib being in the path, even though the linker does seem to be finding /usr/lib.